# Razer Chroma sync compatibility

Tags: cpu, cooling, cpu-cooler, razer-synapse

I just put all my hardware in my Lian Li [pc-o11-dynamic-razer-edition](https://lian-li.com/product/pc-o11-dynamic-razer-edition/) and need to cool my [AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950X (16-core/32-thread)](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-threadripper-1950x) which is a sTR4 package and a motherboard ASRock X399 Taichi sTR4 SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.1/3.0 ATX AMD Motherboard.

I would really like fans compatible with Razer Chroma RGB, but I can't find anything.

Is Razer chroma sync necessary to have an led match or is there a whole family of solutions that would work in this scenario?

Comment: Questions seeking for hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic because they are often relevant only to the question author at the time the question was asked and tend to become obsolete quickly.

Comment: What exactly does Razer RGB products have to do with AMD Ryzen?  Razer most certainly have AIO coolers with RGB that support Razen sockets.

Comment: sorry, was confusing razer and ryzen in my description. fixed